# Adding subviews to UiScrollView .. smoothly

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am trying to dynamically add subviews to a UiScorllView in real time (to save memory).

Doing so causes the scrollview to hang for a brief second... what is the way around this?

any hints appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Read up on the how the `UITableView` solves this problem. Your biggest performance hits here are the allocation and initial drawing of the subview, but primarily the allocation. `UITableView`s use a reuse identifier and an in-memory heap to keep all its cells in memory during scrolling so it can just reuse cells that have already been allocated instead of re-allocating new ones every time a new cell scrolls into the viewable area.

Perhaps you could implement your own subview reuse system to save yourself all that allocation time. Again, read up on specifically how the `UITableView` does it and model yours off of that. Unfortunately, there really is no easier solution than that that I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that any action that could possibly hang the user interface should be placed in a thread. This way, the process of adding the subview will be done in the background, not disturbing the main thread.

You could either do this by `NSThread` or you could implement the `NSOperationQueue`.

Declaration of the NSThread is simple;

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myFunction:) toTarget:myObject withObject:argumentObject];
```

Where 'myFunction' should be replaced with the name of a function, the 'myObject' with an object (or simply state `self` if you want the current class to handle the thread) and 'argumentObject' should be replaced with any object you want to pass along as an argument; this may be `nil`

The function itself should look like this;

```
-(void)myFunction {
   NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];
   // do your thing here...
   [pool release];
}
```

Every thread should have an autorelease pool.

One hint; if your subview has to animate, try declaring a `UIAnimation` block